# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Worksheets' in python win32com.client

Tags: python, excel, worksheet, non-type

```
def messageToCal(path, calculatorName,argList, eventName, fucName,PCBName):
 # location of LED calculator 
    loc = path+calculatorName
    #print loc
    # open excel, run macro called "external_Run" with argList
    xls=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb = xls.Workbooks.Open(Filename=loc)
    try:
        xls.Application.Run("external_Run",argList)
    except Exception as e:
        print "--------------- ERROR ------------------"
        print(e)
        print "=> No data was found, please check your input file"
        raise        
    #xls.Visible = True
    # disable asking dialog when close excel
    xls.DisplayAlerts = False
    # export first sheet (macro output) to csv 
    w=wb.Worksheets(1)
    w.SaveAs(path +'#'+eventName+'_'+fucName+'_'+PCBName.replace(".", "")+'_' +str(argList[3])+ '.csv',6)
    xls.Application.Quit()
    del xls
```

While running this code it throws error as

```
    **w=wb.Worksheets(1)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Worksheets'**
```

Previously it was running fine. Suddenly it throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Something is causing your code to fail to open the workbook correctly. This is causing `wb` to be set to `None`. That is why you are getting an AttributeError when attempting to access `wb.Worksheets(1)`.

If nothing in the code has changed, it's likely that something in your spreadsheet is causing the error. You'll want to verify that the spreadsheet is in the correct location in addition to looking at any recent changes to the spreadsheet to determine what the actual cause of the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the Excel sheet, it's just that your code opens up excel when you run your code, but never closes it i.e. with `wb.close()` in your case.

If you open the Task Manager and click on more details you will see Excel running in the background even after the program has ended.

Yes, you can close it through the task manager each time after running the program, to work with that Excel file again.

Also, if you close it that way and open the file through Excel you will see that Excel provides the history (which will be the exact same data) of that file, as the program was closed abruptly before.

As I mentioned above you can use `wb.close()` and close your workbook through code. Although it will give you an error, but won't affect the outcome of your program in any noticeable way. I applied this patch and it all worked fine(ignoring the unharmful error).

Answer (score 0):

I got this error.
In the properties of the folder containing the file, under General tab, I unticked the 'Read-only' attribute, the error was gone after.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).